# Solving System of ODEs Using Matrix Diagonalisation

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have been given the matrix $A = \begin{bmatrix} -3 & -2 & 2 \\ 0 & 2 & 0 \\ -4 & -1 & 3 \\\end{bmatrix}$.

I firstly needed to find the matrix $P$ that diagonalises it, so I found the eigenvalues of $A$, the corresponding eigenvectors and then constructed $P$ with columns being those eigenvectors. So, $P=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 & 1 \\\end{bmatrix}$ (with the corresponding diagonal matrix $\begin{bmatrix} -1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 2 \\\end{bmatrix}$).

I need to use these results to solve the following system of ODEs:
$$x_1' =-3x_1 -2x_2 +2x_3$$
$$x_2' =2x_2$$
$$x_3' =-4x_1 -x_2 +3x_3$$
where $x_i'=\frac{dx_i}{dt}$.

Now I recognise that the coefficients in the system of ODEs correspond directly to the values of matrix $A$, however I am not sure how to use diagonalisation to solve it? I guess you could set up an equation where **y** $=A$**x** where **y** is a column vector $[x_1', x_2', x_3']$ and **x** is the column vector $[x_1, x_2, x_3]$, however I'm not sure how to go from here? I'm guessing I would use $P$?

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the fact that $A=PDP^{-1}$ we can write the system as **x**'=$A$**x**=$PDP^{-1}$**x** or $(P^{-1}x)^{'}=DP^{-1}x$ so setting $y=P^{-1}x$ we solve $y'=Dy$ (which is easily solved). Then once we know **y**, use **x**=$P$**y** to find x.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\C}{\mathbb{C}}\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}$Suppose you have a (time-independent!) matrix $A\in \C^{n\times n}$ and are looking for a solution $x\colon I\to\C^n$ to the linear ODE
$$x^\prime(t)=Ax(t), x(0)=x_0.\hspace{3em} (1)$$

**Step 1**
First, calculate the Jordan Canonical Form $J$ and the transformation matrix $T$, so that $T^{-1}AT=J$.

**Step 2**
Consider now a solution $z\colon I\to\C^n$ to the linear ODE
$$z^\prime(t)=Jz(t), z(0)=z_0.\hspace{3em} (2)$$
The function $x\colon I\to\C^n, t\mapsto Tz(t)$ is then a solution to (1) for inital value $x_0=Tz_0$:
$$x^\prime(t)=Tz^\prime(t)=TJz(t)=(TJT^{-1})Tz(t)=Ax(t).$$

---

In your case the Jordan Canonical Form is diagonal, therefore the system (2) decouples and you can solve the three independent ODEs
$$z_1^\prime(t)=-z_1(t), \\ z_2^\prime(t)=z_2(t),\\ z_3^\prime(t)=2z_3(t)$$
to obtain
$$z(t)=\begin{pmatrix}e^{-t}&0&0\\0&e^{t}&0\\0&0&e^{2t}\end{pmatrix}z_0=\begin{pmatrix}z_{0,1}e^{-t}\\z_{0,2}e^{t}\\z_{0,3}e^{2t}\end{pmatrix}.$$
Multiply this by the transformation matrix $T$ to obtain the solution to your original ODE.

If the JCF is not diagonal there is a similar formula for the solution to (2).

Answer (score 0):

$$X'=AX$$
where $$A = \begin{pmatrix} -3 & -2 & 2 \\ 0 & 2 & 0 \\ -4 & -1 & 3 \\\end{pmatrix}$$
Since you already have calculated the eignevalues $\lambda_i$ and the eigenvectors $V_i$ then the solution to the system is:
$$X(t)=C_1e^{\lambda_1 t}V_1+C_2e^{\lambda_2 t}V_2+C_3e^{\lambda_3 t}V_3$$

Comment: How did you derive this last equation?

Comment: @RubyPa It's a well known result for differential system. You have three distincts eigenvalues here.